# same message received multiple times

Tags: jms, synchronous

I have an application ONE which continuously reads an incoming folder for files.
Once there are any files available the application reads and publishes to JMS Queue.  Application TWO is listening to the same JMS Queue.
Here the message is published SYNCHRONOUSLY.  So, when the PUBLISHER publishes the message AND just waits until it receives response from the RECEIVER.

The issue that I am facing is that the RECEIVER receiving same message multiple times.

Below are the code snippets for both publishing and receive part.  Could you please highlight where I am going wrong.

### Publisher:

```
public class JMSPublisher {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JMSPublisher.class);
    private static final String MYNAME = JMSPublisher.class.getSimpleName();
    private BytesMessage bytesMessage = null;
    private static final Configuration configuration = Configuration.getInstance();

    public synchronized void publishMessage(String destinationName, Manufacturer manufacturer, String fileName, InputStream is, FileDetails fd) throws JMSException {
        String queueName = null;

        InitialContext initialContext = null;

        Object[] params = new Object[]{};
        try {
            queueName = configuration.getQueueName();
            initialContext = getInitialContext(configuration.getProviderUrl());
            QueueConnectionFactory queueConnectionFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup(configuration.getConnectionFactory());
            QueueConnection queueConnection = queueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
            QueueSession queueSession = queueConnection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            Queue queue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup(configuration.getQueueName());

            queueConnection.start();

            QueueRequestor queueRequestor = new QueueRequestor(queueSession, queue);

            bytesMessage = queueSession.createBytesMessage();

//            boolean writeSuccess = false;
            TextMessage responseMessage = null;
            try {

                bytesMessage.writeBytes(IOUtils.toByteArray(is));
                responseMessage = (TextMessage) queueRequestor.request(bytesMessage);
                params = new Object[]{MYNAME, fileName, queueName, bytesMessage.getJMSMessageID()};
                LOGGER.info("{}: Published  Batch File [{}] to queue [{}] with MessagdID [{}]", params);
                params = new Object[]{MYNAME, bytesMessage.getJMSMessageID(), responseMessage.getJMSCorrelationID(), responseMessage.getJMSDestination(), responseMessage.getJMSTimestamp()};
                LOGGER.info("{}: Response for Message: MessageID [{}]: JMSCorrelationID [{}] JMSDestination [{}] JMSTimestamp [{}] ", params);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                LOGGER.error("{}: Exception occurred while publishing the Batch File [{}] to JMS Queue. Error: [{}]", MYNAME, fileName, ex);

            } finally {
                if (is != null) {
                    try {
                        is.close();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        LOGGER.error(": Error in closing the InputStream for file [{}] with error [{}]", fileName, ex);
                    }
                }
            }
            queueConnection.close();

        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            exceptionOccurred = true;
            LOGGER.error("{}: Naming exception occured [{}]", MYNAME, ex);
        } finally {
            if (initialContext != null) {
                try {
                    initialContext.close();
                } catch (NamingException ex) {
                    LOGGER.error("{}: Naming exception occured while closing initialContext [{}]", MYNAME, ex);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private InitialContext getInitialContext(String url) throws NamingException {
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, configuration.getInitialFactory());
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
        return new InitialContext(env);
    }

}
```

===============================================================================

### Consumer:

```
public class JmsMessageConsumer implements MessageListener, ExceptionListener {


    private QueueConnection queueConnection = null;
    private QueueSession queueSession = null;
    private InitialContext initialContext = null;
    private Configuration cfg = null;    
    private AbstractApplicationContext ctx = null;
    private Configuration config = Configuration.getInstance();
    private String majorReturnCode = MajorReturnCode.INTERNAL_ERROR;
    private String minorReturnCode = MinorReturnCode.INTERNAL_ERROR;
    private QueueConnectionFactory queueConnectionFactory = null;
    private Queue queue = null;
    private QueueReceiver queueReceiver = null;

    public void init() throws NamingException, ConfigException {
        cfg = Configuration.getInstance();
        initialContext = getInitialContext(cfg.getProviderUrl());
        queueConnectionFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup(cfg.getConnectionFactory());
        queue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup(cfg.getSimBatchQueue());
        getConnection();
    }

    public void onException(JMSException jmse) {
        LOGGER.error("{}.init().onException(): Connection to JMS Queue lost. Error [{}]", MYNAME, jmse.getMessage());
        getConnection();
    }

    public void getConnection() {

        try {
            queueConnection = queueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
            queueSession = queueConnection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            queueReceiver = queueSession.createReceiver(queue);
            queueReceiver.setMessageListener(this);
            queueConnection.setExceptionListener(this);
            queueConnection.start();
            LOGGER.info("{}.getConnection(): Connected to JMS Queue", MYNAME);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error("{}.getConnection(): Exception occured. Error {{}]", MYNAME, ex);
            getConnection();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {

        TextMessage replyMessage = null;
        QueueSender replyToSender = null;

        try {

            BufferedReader br = null;
String simBatchFileName = message.getStringProperty("simBatchFileName");
            LOGGER.info("{}: Message received for Batch File [{}]", MYNAME,simBatchFileName );
            InputStream jmsMessageConsumer = new BytesMessageInputStream((BytesMessage) message);

                byte[] inputBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(jmsMessageConsumer);              
                BytesMessage bytesMessage = (BytesMessage) message;
                Queue replyTo = (Queue) bytesMessage.getJMSReplyTo();
                replyToSender = queueSession.createSender(replyTo);
                replyMessage = queueSession.createTextMessage();

                setReplyMessage(replyMessage, isSimBatchFileValid, isTimOrderValid, isValidCustomer, timOrderNumber, customerName, validateTimOrder, errorMsg);


        } catch (JMSException e) {
            LOGGER.error("{}.onMessage(): JMSException occured with error: [{}]", MYNAME, e);
            errorMsg = "JMSException occured with error: " + e.getMessage();

            try {
                if (replyToSender != null) {
                    replyToSender.send(replyMessage);
                }

            } catch (JMSException ex) {
                LOGGER.error("{}.onMessage(): JMSException occured in re-sending the reply: [{}]", MYNAME, ex);
                errorMsg = "JMSException occured with error: " + ex.getMessage();

            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            LOGGER.error("{}: Error in reading the message - [{}]", MYNAME, ex);

        }
    }


    private InitialContext getInitialContext(String url) throws NamingException {
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, cfg.getInitialFactory());
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
        System.setProperty("weblogic.MaxMessageSize", config.getMaxJmsMsgSize());
        return new InitialContext(env);
    }

    private void setReplyMessage(TextMessage replyMessage, boolean isSimBatchFileValid, boolean isTimOrderValid, boolean isValidCustomer, String timOrderNumber, String customerName, boolean validateTimOrder, String errorMsg) throws JMSException {
        replyMessage.setBooleanProperty("isSimBatchFileValid", isSimBatchFileValid);
        replyMessage.setBooleanProperty("isTimOrderValid", isTimOrderValid);
        replyMessage.setBooleanProperty("isValidCustomer", isValidCustomer);
        replyMessage.setStringProperty("timOrderNumber", timOrderNumber);
        replyMessage.setStringProperty("customerCode", customerName);
        replyMessage.setBooleanProperty("validateTimOrder", validateTimOrder);
        replyMessage.setStringProperty("simBatchHeaderId", (batchHeaderId != null) ? batchHeaderId.toString() : null);
        replyMessage.setStringProperty("majorReturnCode", this.getMajorReturnCode());
        replyMessage.setStringProperty("minorReturnCode", this.getMinorReturnCode());
        replyMessage.setStringProperty("errorMsg", errorMsg);
    }
}
```

==================================================================

### Logs:

Line 1: 2017-05-04 12:14:31,590  INFO [ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'default'] - JmsMessageConsumer: Message received for Batch File [File3_crc_5_1493900070455.csv]
    Line 68: 2017-05-04 12:14:32,917  INFO [ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'default'] - JmsMessageConsumer: Message received for Batch File [File2_crc_2_1493900070423.csv]
    Line 117: 2017-05-04 12:14:33,665  INFO [ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'default'] - JmsMessageConsumer: Message received for Batch File [File2_crc_4.csv]
    Line 140: 2017-05-04 12:14:33,725  INFO [ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'default'] - JmsMessageConsumer: Message received for Batch File [File2_crc_2_1493900070423.csv]
    Line 183: 2017-05-04 12:14:33,793  INFO [ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'default'] - JmsMessageConsumer: Message received for Batch File [File3_crc_5_1493900070455.csv]
    Line 205: 2017-05-04 12:14:33,814  INFO [ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'default'] - JmsMessageConsumer: Message received for Batch File [File1_crc_1_1493900070380.csv]
    Line 229: 2017-05-04 12:14:33,846  INFO [ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'default'] - JmsMessageConsumer: Message received for Batch File [File2_crc_5_1493900070433.csv]
    Line 328: 2017-05-04 12:14:34,108  INFO [ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'default'] - JmsMessageConsumer: Message received for Batch File [File2_crc_5_1493900070433.csv]
    Line 363: 2017-05-04 12:14:34,143  INFO [ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'default'] - JmsMessageConsumer: Message received for Batch File [File4_crc_2_1493900070465.csv]
    Line 399: 2017-05-04 12:14:34,192  INFO [ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'default'] - JmsMessageConsumer: Message received for Batch File [File1_crc_4.csv]
    Line 489: 2017-05-04 12:14:34,435  INFO [ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'default'] - JmsMessageConsumer: Message received for Batch File [File3_crc_1.csv]
    Line 493: 2017-05-04 12:14:34,436  INFO [ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'default'] - JmsMessageConsumer: Message received for Batch File [File4_crc_1.csv]
    Line 523: 2017-05-04 12:14:34,454  INFO [ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'default'] - JmsMessageConsumer: Message received for Batch File [File1_crc_5.csv]
    Line 575: 2017-05-04 12:14:34,499  INFO [ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'default'] - JmsMessageConsumer: Message received for Batch File [File1_crc_2.csv]
    Line 643: 2017-05-04 12:14:34,812  INFO [ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'default'] - JmsMessageConsumer: Message received for Batch File [File1_crc_4.csv]
    Line 685: 2017-05-04 12:14:34,866  INFO [ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'default'] - JmsMessageConsumer: Message received for Batch File [File2_crc_3_1493900070427.csv]
    Line 729: 2017-05-04 12:14:34,900  INFO [ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'default'] - JmsMessageConsumer: Message received for Batch File [File1_crc_5.csv]
    Line 753: 2017-05-04 12:14:34,917  INFO [ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'default'] - JmsMessageConsumer: Message received for Batch File [File4_crc_3_1493900070468.csv]
    Line 798: 2017-05-04 12:14:34,953  INFO [ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'default'] - JmsMessageConsumer: Message received for Batch File [File4_crc_1.csv]
    Line 871: 2017-05-04 12:14:35,016  INFO [ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'default'] - JmsMessageConsumer: Message received for Batch File [File3_crc_2_1493900070440.csv]
    Line 911: 2017-05-04 12:14:35,051  INFO [ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'default'] - JmsMessageConsumer: Message received for Batch File [File1_crc_3_1493900070408.csv]
    Line 987: 2017-05-04 12:14:35,268  INFO [ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'default'] - JmsMessageConsumer: Message received for Batch File [File3_crc_4_1493900070446.csv]
    Line 1014: 2017-05-04 12:14:35,823  INFO [ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'default'] - JmsMessageConsumer: Message received for Batch File [File4_crc_5.csv]
    Line 1015: 2017-05-04 12:14:35,823  INFO [ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'default'] - JmsMessageConsumer: Message received for Batch File [File4_crc_4.csv]